# Azure Runbook Start/Stop Schedule Lists

Tags: azure, azure-automation, runbook

I've set up a Runbook using the Start/Stop templates from the Gallery.

All set up, no errors, no warnings. 
Why don't any of the schedules appear under the "Schedule Runbook" but appear elsewhere in the Azure portal?

[Runbook_Blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfqoB.png)
[Scheduler_List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xylZa.png)

Answer (score 1):

> Why don't any of the schedules appear under the "Schedule Runbook" but
>   appear elsewhere in the Azure portal?

Because you create the `autoStopVM` schedule in Azure Automation Account, this schedule just a time settings, not associate any runbook with it.

But Runbook schedule is the schedule with runbook and time settings.

There are different things.

For example, I create a **empty** schedule `test3` in Automation account, like this:

[image]

Then we can find this schedule in runbook schedule setting page:

[image]

But this just a schedule, we can't find it in runbook schedule list:
[image]

So, automation account schedule **not equal to** runbook schedule.

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)