# Azure automation schedule not saving

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

Ok, haven't seen this posted on here. I am at a loss on what to do.

So i created a schedule to run a runbook. Nothing fancy, just to run my runbook every sunday at midnight. This runbook executes a stored proc to auto index files and statistics.

So after setting everything up, tested the runbook and it works fine, published, but when i am assigning a schedule to my runbook, the schedule list is blank. I tried creating then recreating, relinking my schedule but the schedule just won't save. I have attached a gif here so you can see what i mean.

[GIF of azure not saving schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1dSK.gif)
Has something like this happened to you guys? I'm at a loss on what i could be doing wrong.

Comment: You need to post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automation account schedule **not equal to** runbook schedule.

We can find them in runbook schedule list.

Here a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927666/azure-runbook-start-stop-schedule-lists/47935065#47935065) about you, please refer to it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That’s it! Runbook schedule set succesfully. Thanks! I was looking at shared resources and not runbook specific.